# data in textbox from database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

i want to fetch all data of a column in textbox from database in form of list like combobox.
this is my code.

```
    CON.Open();
    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT CUST_NAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID=CUST_NAME", CON);
    SqlDataReader DR = CMD.ExecuteReader();

    while (DR.Read())
    {
        CUST_NAME.Text = DR["CUST_NAME"].ToString();
    }
    CON.Close();
```

so please help me

Comment: `In form of list in a textbox` - could you elaborate on this?

Comment: use combobox instead, write this combobox.items.add(DR["CUST_NAME"].ToString()); instead of CUST_NAME.Text = DR["CUST_NAME"].ToString();

Answer (score 1):

you should make your text box multiple line and re size it

```
CUST_NAME.Multiline = true;
```

then change your code to

```
    CON.Open();
    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT CUST_NAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID=CUST_NAME", CON);
    SqlDataReader DR = CMD.ExecuteReader();

    while (DR.Read())
    {
        CUST_NAME.Text = DR["CUST_NAME"].ToString() + "\r\n";
    }
    CON.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

need a small change.

```
CON.Open();
SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT CUST_NAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID=CUST_NAME", CON);
SqlDataReader DR = CMD.ExecuteReader();

while (DR.Read())
{
    CUST_NAME.Text += DR["CUST_NAME"].ToString() + "\r\n";
}
CON.Close();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Binding to a combo box from a `DataReader` would look like this:

```
CON.Open();
SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT CUST_NAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID=CUST_NAME", CON);
SqlDataReader DR = CMD.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(DR);
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CUST_NAME";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "CUST_ID";
CON.Close();
```